# Sitecore Docker Development Image for MS SQL Server 2019

Tags: docker, sql-database, container

The Sitecore container registry contains `mssql-developer` images for Windows OS targeting only MS SQL Server 2017 (see full list [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/docker-images/master/tags/sitecore-tags.md)).

The Microsoft Artifact Registry contains only MS SQL Server images for Linux OS: https://mcr.microsoft.com/en-us/catalog?search=sql

If I want to use an MS SQL Server image for Windows OS targeting an higher version of SQL Server, for example MS SQL server 2019, what should I do?

Comment: The underlying OS for this specific use is unlikely to make much of a difference, if any at all. Especially if you are truly using ephemeral containers in production. What issues did you experience with the linux based images?

Comment: This image, like the Sitecore distributed `mssql-developer` image, is meant for local development only, not for production. On my Windows laptop, I've experienced issues with mounting volumes (for data persistence) from my Windows host environment with Linux-based images, so I preferred to use a Windows-based image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should build your own custom Windows based SQL Server image, targeting the desired version.

The following steps describe how to do it, targeting MS SQL Server 2019.

#### Step 1 - Create a dockerfile spec file:

The dockerfile should define the following build steps:

- Use a Microsoft servercore image as base image
- Define needed environment variables
- Copy entrypoint script (same used in Sitecore `mssql-developer` images images)
- Download and install the desired MS SQL Server software as a service
- Configure TCP ports and SQL Server login mode
- Define Healthcheck command
- Define image startup command

Example of `dockerfile` for MS SQL Server 2019 Windows image:

```
# escape=`
# This Dockerfile is used to generate images for the following roles: mssql

ARG BASE_IMAGE

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

ENV sa_password="_" `
    attach_dbs="[]" `
    ACCEPT_EULA="_" `
    sa_password_path="C:\ProgramData\Docker\secrets\sa-password" `
    DATA_PATH="C:\data"

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Overwrite base entrypoint with custom one
COPY \tools\entrypoints .

WORKDIR /

RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/4/c/84c6c430-e0f5-476d-bf43-eaaa222a72e0/SQLServer2019-DEV-x64-ENU.exe" -OutFile SQL.exe; `
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/4/c/84c6c430-e0f5-476d-bf43-eaaa222a72e0/SQLServer2019-DEV-x64-ENU.box" -OutFile SQL.box; `
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://download.microsoft.com/download/f/1/9/f19eaee6-0728-4a0b-9755-9808acc8af0b/EN/x64/DacFramework.msi" -OutFile C:\DacFramework.msi; `
    Start-Process -Wait -FilePath .\SQL.exe -ArgumentList /qs, /x:setup; `
    .\setup\setup.exe /q /ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /FEATURES=SQLEngine /SQLUSERDBDIR=$env:DATA_PATH /UPDATEENABLED=0 /SQLSVCACCOUNT='NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS='BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS' /TCPENABLED=1 /NPENABLED=0 /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE='Manual'; `
    Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait msiexec.exe -ArgumentList /i, C:\DacFramework.msi, /quiet, /norestart; `
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force SQL.exe, SQL.box, setup, C:\DacFramework.msi;

RUN set-itemproperty -path 'HKLM:\software\microsoft\microsoft sql server\mssql15.MSSQLSERVER\mssqlserver\supersocketnetlib\tcp\ipall' -name tcpdynamicports -value ''; `
    set-itemproperty -path 'HKLM:\software\microsoft\microsoft sql server\mssql15.MSSQLSERVER\mssqlserver\supersocketnetlib\tcp\ipall' -name tcpport -value 1433; `
    set-itemproperty -path 'HKLM:\software\microsoft\microsoft sql server\mssql15.MSSQLSERVER\mssqlserver\' -name LoginMode -value 2;

HEALTHCHECK CMD ["sqlcmd","-Q","SELECT 1"]

CMD .\start -sa_password $env:sa_password -ACCEPT_EULA $env:ACCEPT_EULA -attach_dbs \"$env:attach_dbs\" -DataDirectory $env:DATA_PATH -Verbose
```

NOTE: Use different download link to target different MS SQL Server software versions. Installation parameters might vary across SQL Server versions as well.

#### Step 2 - Configure the build command for the `mssql` service in the `docker-compose.override.yml` file of your project

Your `docker-compose.override.yml` file might already have a build command for the `mssql` service. If it doesn't, add the following section:

```
mssql:
    ...
    build:
      context: ./docker/build/mssql
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:${OS_IMAGE_TAG}
```

The configuration above uses the `OS_IMAGE_TAG` environment variable to specify the Windows OS targeting version (ie. `ltsc-2019`).

#### Step 3 - Copy the `Start.ps1` entrypoint script in your host build folder

One of the build steps in the `dockerfile` described at Step 1 above copies a custom entrypoint start script from the build host machine inside the image. The build step is expecting the start script to be located in the `\tools\entrypoints` folder relative to the location of the build context (`./docker/build/mssql`) defined in the `docker-compose.override.yml` file described at Step 2 above.

The original `Start.ps1` script can be copied and exported from one of the Sitecore `mssql-developer` images, or copied from here below:

```
# The script sets the sa password and start the SQL Service
# Also it attaches additional database from the disk
# The format for attach_dbs

param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$sa_password,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$ACCEPT_EULA,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$attach_dbs,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateScript({ Test-Path $_ -PathType Container })]
    [string]$DataDirectory
)


if ($ACCEPT_EULA -ne "Y" -And $ACCEPT_EULA -ne "y") {
    Write-Verbose "ERROR: You must accept the End User License Agreement before this container can start."
    Write-Verbose "Set the environment variable ACCEPT_EULA to 'Y' if you accept the agreement."

    exit 1
}

# start the service
Write-Verbose "Starting SQL Server"
start-service MSSQLSERVER

# Enable Contained Database Authentication
Write-Verbose "Enabling contained database authentication"
& sqlcmd -Q "sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1; RECONFIGURE;"

if ($sa_password -eq "_") {
    if (Test-Path $env:sa_password_path) {
        $sa_password = Get-Content -Raw $secretPath
    }
    else {
        Write-Verbose "WARN: Using default SA password, secret file not found at: $secretPath"
    }
}

if ($sa_password -ne "_") {
    Write-Verbose "Changing SA login credentials"
    $sqlcmd = "ALTER LOGIN sa with password=" + "'" + $sa_password + "'" + ";ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE;"
    & sqlcmd -Q $sqlcmd
}

#Attach databases in data directory
Get-ChildItem -Path $DataDirectory -Filter "*.mdf" | ForEach-Object {
    $databaseName = $_.BaseName.Replace("_Primary", "")
    $mdfPath = $_.FullName

    $primaryDbEnding = $_.Name.Replace(".mdf", ".ldf")
    $logDbEnding = $databaseName + "_log.ldf"
    
    $ldfPath = Get-ChildItem -Path $DataDirectory | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $primaryDbEnding -or $_.Name -eq $logDbEnding }
    $ldfPath = $ldfPath.FullName
    $sqlcmd = "IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE NAME = '$databaseName') BEGIN EXEC sp_detach_db [$databaseName] END;CREATE DATABASE [$databaseName] ON (FILENAME = N'$mdfPath'), (FILENAME = N'$ldfPath') FOR ATTACH;"

    Write-Host "INFO: Attaching '$databaseName'..."

    & sqlcmd -Q $sqlcmd
}

#attach additional databases from parameter
$attach_dbs_cleaned = $attach_dbs.TrimStart('\\').TrimEnd('\\')

$dbs = $attach_dbs_cleaned | ConvertFrom-Json

if ($null -ne $dbs -And $dbs.Length -gt 0) {
    Write-Verbose "Attaching $($dbs.Length) database(s)"
    
    Foreach ($db in $dbs) {            
        $files = @();
        Foreach ($file in $db.dbFiles) {
            $files += "(FILENAME = N'$($file)')";           
        }

        $files = $files -join ","
        $sqlcmd = "IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE NAME = '" + $($db.dbName) + "') BEGIN EXEC sp_detach_db [$($db.dbName)] END;CREATE DATABASE [$($db.dbName)] ON $($files) FOR ATTACH;"

        Write-Verbose "Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $($sqlcmd)"
        & sqlcmd -Q $sqlcmd
    }
}

Write-Verbose "Started SQL Server."

$lastCheck = (Get-Date).AddSeconds(-2) 
while ($true) { 
    Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "MSSQL*" -After $lastCheck | Select-Object TimeGenerated, EntryType, Message 
    $lastCheck = Get-Date 
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 
}
```

#### Step 4 - Build the custom image

As last step, build the custom MS SQL image executing the `docker-compose build mssql` command in Windows Powershell in the folder where the `docker-compose.override.yml` file is located.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro, worked for me. Would be great if someone had the SQL 2022 download links, can't find them anywhere.

Comment: Thank you Alessando. FYI, I had to use 'ltsc2019'. 'ltsc-2019' does not seem to exist.